# Want to display latest foursquare checkin's

Tags: html, foursquare

I have around 100 locations and would like to display the last five locations that have been checked in on my website and who by...

I'm wondering if this is possible and how to go about it?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on what kind of questions are welcome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot view a user's check-ins without the user authenticating your application.

See: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/community

However, there is a source of public check-in information. Some users choose to share their checkins with Twitter. These checkins are public (anyone can see the details via the URL), so you could use that in some way.

Hope that helps